# Can PMD be used for dataflow analysis on Java?

Tags: pmd

i'd like to know if i can use PMD to perform some basic data flow analysis actions. It's an assignment so it doesn't matter if it's trivial. 
I can't find any code examples online.

Is the DFA module working? Should i go the reverse engineering way to see what's going on?

Thanks lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PMD's Data Flow Analysis module is operational. There are rules using it shipping with PMD, for instance [DataflowAnomalyAnalysis](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.3/pmd-java/rules/java/controversial.html#DataflowAnomalyAnalysis).

However, it is true the PMD team [plans to revamp that implementation](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/wiki/Project-Ideas-%5BInception%5D#data-flow-analysis-and-control-flow-graph) at some point in the future.

DFA is only usable through Java rules (XPath rules can't be used). Writing a DFA rule consists of:

1. Writing a visitor in which you get the DFA node for the method / constructor you want to analyze:

   ```
   public Object visit(ASTMethodDeclaration methodDeclaration, Object data) {
       final DataFlowNode node = methodDeclaration.getDataFlowNode().getFlow().get(0);

       final DAAPathFinder pathFinder = new DAAPathFinder(node, executable, getProperty(MAX_PATH_DESCRIPTOR));
       pathFinder.run();
       return data;
   }
   ```
2. Writing a proper `Executable` to enforce your rule.

   ```
   public void execute(CurrentPath path) {
       // your code here to analyze the current path
   }
   ```

A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/controversial/DataflowAnomalyAnalysisRule.java)

Comment: You'll also have to add the `dfa="true"` attribute in your rule xml, otherwise `getDataFlowNode()` will always return null